# Submit to open up a popup window and carry through input data

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a input box on one page that on submit opens a new page with a longer form and the first field is populated with what was entered from the previous pages input box.  So on page 1 there is this code:

```
<form action="sign-up.php">
<input  type="text" name="email" value="sign up for email" onFocus="clearText(this)" onBlur="clearText(this)" style="float: left;">     
<input value='Submit' /> </form>
```

Then on the sign-up page the receiving form grabs the string out of the url

```
//<!-- Begin
function getParams() {
    var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
    if (idx != -1) {
        var tempParams = new Object();
        var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1,document.URL.length).split('&');
        for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
            nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
            tempParams[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
        }
        return tempParams;
    }
}
var params = getParams();
// End -->
```

I would like to keep all of this functionality but it have it occur in a popup.  I added this function to the submit:

```
function myPopup() {
window.open( "sign-up.php", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0" )
```

and the form becomes

```
<form>
  <input  type="text" name="email" value="sign up for email" onFocus="clearText(this)" onBlur="clearText(this)" style="float: left;">       
    <input  onClick="myPopup()" value='Submit' /> </form>
```

But it no longer appends the input data to the url string.  Anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying your URL in window.open() with no parameters. Instead of `"sign-up.php"`, why don't you have `"signup-php?arg1=something&arg2=something-else"` etc. You'll have to write some code to get the parameter values from the form, but this is easy enough.

If I understand your question correctly, this seems to be what's missing???